# Why my System.Windows.Data.Binding fails with a DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, data-binding, dependency-properties

I got the following code for my object (short version) :

```
public class PluginClass
{
    public int MyInt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PluginClass()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            MyInt = random.Next(0, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm creating another class with an int as a DependencyProperty. Here is the code (simplified version too)

```
public class MyClass : FrameworkElement
{
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(MyClass ), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public MyClass(object source, string propertyName)
    {
        var b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding();
        b.Source = source;
        b.Path = new PropertyPath(propertyName);
        b.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay;

        SetBinding(ValueProperty, b);
    }
}
```

Finally I'm creating an instance of PluginClass and I'd like to bind my "MyInt" value to the int of MyClass. Here is what I got (simplified version too)

```
PluginClass pc = new PluginClass();
MyClass mc = new MyClass(pc, "MyInt");
```

No compilation problem but the binding is not effective.
To summarise, I don't know if I theorically have to got :

```
binding.Source = PluginClass.MyInt;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("???"); // don't know what to "ask"
```

or

```
binding.Source = PluginClass;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("MyInt");
```

I think the 2nd way is the good one but I don't know why it doesn't work :(
Any help will be very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PluginClass` should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). For now, the binding has no idea the value of `MyInt` has changed.

Implementing INPC will allow your class to inform the binding when the value changes (you will have to raise `PropertyChanged` in your set function of `MyInt`).

Comment: I was thinking about it but I concluded that it was something else! will give it a try :)